# Is combining `using` statements same as doing them one-by-one?

Tags: c#

*Note: I'm sorry for the weird title but I cannot figure out any better title, feel free to edit.*

So I have very simple question regarding `using` block in C#. I know what it does and why to use it on IO and network operations however I need to know if grouping them is OK since if I have multiple of them it's too much identation.

So basically the question is simple: Are these two functions underneath are the same? Or I should use the latter one with the multi-level indentation?

```
public static async Task ReadStuffUsingTogether()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync("http://bigfile.com/file.csv", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    using (var fileStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    using (var writeStream = File.Open("1.csv", FileMode.Create))
    {
        await fileStream.CopyToAsync(writeStream);
    }
}

// Too much identation in my opinion
public static async Task ReadStuffUsing()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var response = await client.GetAsync("http://bigfile.com/file.csv", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
        {
            using (var fileStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                using (var writeStream = File.Open("1.csv", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await fileStream.CopyToAsync(writeStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uhm, well it is the same. The rules here are the same as for nested ‘if’ statements :

```
if(x) 
if(y) 
if(z) DoSomething();
```

Or:

```
if(x)
{
   if(y) 
   {
       if(z)
       {
           DoSomething(); 
           .. some other code
       }
   }
}
```

The main difference between the two is that with curly brackets it is possible to add a *block* of code whilst without - only one line

Comment: I find it quite strange to claim inproved readability for nested `using` blocks . However especially for `if` statement the code tends to get expanded and having the braces in place makes this much less erroror prone. Not to speak of the else clauses..A block of using statements is however much clearer and avoids crazy indentation levels that are in fact hard to follow. My 2 cents.

Comment: @TaW Well, I think it's up to developer to decide which coding conventions to use and how to write his code (as long this code is ok). I just added that part regarding improved readability for OP to show him that this is something that he might consider when he's writing the code.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But I can't help disagreeing to `using` and `if` nesting being the same wrt readability. But to each his own..

Comment: @TaW Well, it based on ones opinion and experience. I don't think it's entirely the same, but I'd either add braces in both scenarios or not add at all. Alright, updated my answer and removed this part as it's off-topic to the question

Answer (score 4):

Yes, combining them in your case is exactly the same as doing them one-by-one.

The syntax of `using` opens a single-statement scope, in the same way as a `for` loop or an `if` statement does. You formatted them one on top of the other; indenting would change nothing, because C# ignores whitespace:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync("http://bigfile.com/file.csv", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
        using (var fileStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            using (var writeStream = File.Open("1.csv", FileMode.Create))
            {
                await fileStream.CopyToAsync(writeStream);
            }
```

It limits your usage slightly, because you cannot add more code after one `using` ends but before the next one ends:

```
using (var fileStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
{
    using (var writeStream = File.Open("1.csv", FileMode.Create))
    {
        await fileStream.CopyToAsync(writeStream);
    }
    // Do something else with fileStream
    log.Info("Read {0} bytes from fileStream", fileStream.Position);
}
```

However, if this is not necessary, you can skip nesting of curly braces.

Answer (score 2):

They are exactly the same, you're taking advantage of the fact that any block with only one statement can omit the `{` and `}`

its essentailly the same as doing this

```
if(someCondition)
    Console.WriteLine("foo");
```